# manual function to prevent mysql injection without prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a website which uses a custom function for addslashes on all mysql queries like this:

```
function custom_addslashes($str) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Recently I found out mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated.
I have two options. Either

1. go through the entire site and convert to prepared statements for every page, (argh) or
2. modify the above function. I assume it is impossible to modify the above function to use PDO, since it is used for many different queries.

Is there a good way to do option 2.
something like?

```
function custom_addslashes($str) {
    return  strtr($str, array("\0" => "", "\\" => "&#92;","'","\\'"));
}
```

clarifed the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Why custom function when you have perfectly working bultin functions.?

Comment: You should probably look into prepared statements with PDO/MYSQLi.

Comment: @User016 because i dont want to use the PDO/Mysqli . too complicated. and mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo not duplicate. i saw that and am asking if there's a way to do it without the prepared statements

Comment: too complicated? it's like 1 line of code if you're not binding parameters $stmt->prepare($query) how is that complicated?

Comment: You are asking your question out of awful wrong assumptions. Say, what function you are going to use to run your query? mysqli_query(), I suppose. do you have an idea that this function is deprecated too?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne the reason is I have a website which uses a custom function for addslashes. namely function ($str) {return mysql_real_escape_string($str);} To convert to prepared statement i would need to go thru every page of the site instead of just modifying this function.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that was probably a typo on your part, but mysqli_query is not deprecated. i'm guessing you meant mysql_query, as all of the mysql_ functions are deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @RayS. your best alternative (and yes this will still involve you going through your entire site) would be to switch from mysql_ functions which will be removed from php soon, and switching to mysqli_ functions. they're structured similar to the mysql_ ones, so the conversion would be pretty simple, and they have a real escape string function that you can use in your custom function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @JeffHawthorne yeah, he's got it already. at last.

Comment: @Ray S.: So you are using prepared statement ? If yes what are you using PDO or any other library ?

Comment: @SantoshPradhan mysql_i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that enough for all scenarios?

**NO.**

> if not, what should be added?

**prepared statement**

> i dont want to use the PDO/Mysqli . too complicated. and mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated.

I've never in my life would expect such a conclusion.

Comment: so you're saying there's no way to do this with a simple function

Comment: yes. however, it can be done with other simple function that supports prepared statements

Comment: i clarified my reason for doing it this way in the question. thnx

Comment: Unfortunately, your reasons are all the same - based on wrong assumptions and thus make no sense.

Comment: what doesn't make sense? it's much less work to modify a function than to go thru every page on a website. :-)

Comment: ah, i see. didn't realize mysql_query is also deprecated. if they take out that function it will take down a large percentage of older php driven websites.